# JavaScript - axios GET request, push to array but return error with promise.all

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to make GET request to a free API and return an array of all French departments as a result. Initially, I was getting empty result, which then I understood I wasn't wait for GET request to end. So I used the promise.all to make sure it waited but it doesn't work, I still get errors and undefined result. This is the code:

make array of departments:

```
const axios = require('axios')

let postalCode_all = []

for(let i = 1; i < 97; i++) {

    if(i < 10){
        postalCode_all.push("0" + i)
    } else {
        postalCode_all.push(i)
    }
}
```

Prepare the GET request to API:

```
let departements = [];

async function use_api(dep)  {

        try {
            const response = await axios.get("https://geo.api.gouv.fr/departements/" + dep + "?fields=region");
            departements.push(response);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
```

Make the GET request on all of the array firstly made:

```
(async () => {
    const result = await Promise.all(
        postalCode_all.map(element => {
            return use_api(element);
        })
    )
    console.log(result)
})()
```

Edit:
Errors (404) probably comes from departments like number 20 that doesn't exist, so I think my real issue is array of undefined, I will think about it.

Comment: What do you see in the Response tab of the Network tab of your request when you send the request?

Comment: @LajosArpad a long list of errors which included response: {
    status: 404 or [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404] {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST' ; after all those errors I have array of undefined ; maybe the errors comes from departments that doesn't exist! So only undefined might be the real problem?

Okay number 20 doesn't exist as department, which cause one of those errors, maybe I can ignore all errors and I will think about why it's an array of undefined

Comment: Based on your answer to my comment it very much seems that you have an issue with the request itself. Can you copy the URL from the Request tab of the Network tab of your Dev Tools and paste it to the address bar of a browser tab?

Comment: @LajosArpad, Razvan Rusu got it working, but thank you too for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried running your code and I found a couple of issues but I think I've got it working.
The first problem is here:

```
const response = await axios.get("https://geo.api.gouv.fr/departements/" + dep + "?fields=region");
departements.push(response);
```

Here, `response` is the whole HTTP request object - I presume you're only interested in the actual data, not the headers, so we should do this instead:

```
departements.push(response.data);
```

Secondly, in the `use_api()` function, you are only pushing the data to `departements` and then not using this array to print them.
To see the results with your current code, instead of

```
console.log(result)
```

you need to do

```
console.log(departements)
```

and use that array.

Comment: I see! The final result was indeed in let departements = [] and not in my const result as I thought... Thank you, I think I understand a little better why I failed.